# Visual Studio extension- Interactive error popup

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I've got a Visual Studio extension that I am working on. I have implemented some error tagging, which works just fine. However, some of the errors reference other locations in the code. I would like that the user can click on these locations and be taken there. The definition for ErrorTag permits an Object as the tooltip, which is not terrifically helpful, and the documentation seemed quite resistant as to what this should actually be. So far I have only been able to use a String as a tooltip.

In addition, the error popup is destroyed when the user leaves the error text span. I would need it to remain whilst the user is still on the text span *or* the popup content. I have discovered a [PopupStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.text.adornments.popupstyles.aspx) enumeration which can control this behaviour, but I am unsure how to apply it. I would need to use the DismissOnMouseLeaveTextOrContent member to set the appropriate behaviour.

How can I implement an interactive error tooltip?

Edit: I discovered that a UIElement is a valid argument here- I replaced the String with a Label, for example. Some formatting issues aside, I still need to know how to change the popup style.

Answer (score 0):

The error popup is intended to be a static tooltip and nothing more. It's not supposed to be interactive.

The PopupStyles enumeration appears to be used for the [ISpaceReservationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.ispacereservationmanager.aspx) and [IToolTipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.adornments.itooltipprovider.aspx) -- there's no real connection to the tagging API at all. What you might be able to do is listen for the IWpfTextView.MouseHover event, and then use one of these APIs to trigger the tooltip that can be interacted with.

Comment: I have indeed attempted this solution. I shipped an IErrorTag without a TooltipContent, then listened for MouseHover and used an IToolTipProvider. Unfortunately, not only is all of the styling lost, but the popup style doesn't even work- the text is dismissed just like before even though I used DismissOnMouseLeaveTextOrContent.